# Why does Wolfram Alpha give $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(e^i)^{n^2}\approx9.92988+1.76807i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, wolfram-alpha

When I input 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(e^i)^{n^2}$$
in Wolfram Alpha, it gives me the result,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(e^i)^{n^2}\approx9.92988+1.76807i$$
I think this is wrong, but I do not understand why Wolfram Alpha does that. Any suggestions why this happens? Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is wrong?

Comment: The sum it presents is the sum up to $n=200$.

Comment: @Winther: You are right, now I understand. I am kind of surprised that Wolfram Alpha stops at 200. Maybe it is just the code.

Comment: @user254433: Could you explain what you mean by the partial sums converge? I think that the partial sums for $\cos(n^2)$ are not bounded.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is pretty fuzzy. You type in an expression and it tries to guess what you want and present some possibly useful information about it. One of the outputs when it thinks you have an infinite sum it can't compute, but it can't prove divergence, is the sum of the first 200 terms and let you hope for the best. A bit lame but at least it does tell you it couldn't prove convergence.

Comment: Uh ... how can the partial sums converge when the terms which have unit modulus do not approach zero?

Comment: Terms still have to approach zero and their modulus must do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting. The answer is clearly wrong: the real part of the result is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(n^2)$ and the imaginary part is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n^2)$. 
It is quite clear that both of these sums are divergent: the sequences $\cos(n^2)$ and $\sin(n^2)$ are not even null-sequences. 
Interestingly, wolfram realizes this: try $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(n^2)$, for example.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly why I think Wolfram Alpha is wrong.

Comment: To be fair, it said that the ratio test was inconclusive, so it wasn't sure if the sum was convergent or not... I never saw the source code of wolfram, but I guess it runs a couple of tests to check if the sum converges, and if they do not work, it computes some value, say the 1000000th term of the sequence. I mean, what else could it really do, being unable to think? So it should be unreliable when it comes to questions like this.